# IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 when using Pandas to covert CSV colums to lists

Tags: python, pandas, csv, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

Trying to make a relatively simple script to help automate some comment writing I have to do. I'm playing around with how to structure and interact with the data and decided to try using Pandas since it seemed pretty robust and straight forward. I want to extract each column of my csv files as a list, and then append some of them to different lists of lists. Except anytime I try to do anything with the files I get this error:`IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`. I've been searching around for how to fix it but I'm not really sure what the issue is. I've tweaked the code and data a bunch of different ways (try,except statements, checking for zero length indexes before execution, double checking data sets to make sure it's aligned correctly. Still, no closer to an answer. So, here is the latest version of the code I've been playing with and the files I'm reading. I hope someone can help.

```
from pandas import read_csv

intro = read_csv('/home/patrick/Desktop/DataTest/intro.csv')
names_m = read_csv('/home/patrick/Desktop/DataTest/testDataM.csv')
intro_1 = intro[intro.columns[0]].tolist()
intro_2 = intro[intro.columns[1]].tolist()
master_list_m = intro.values.tolist()

print(intro_1)

intro
"intros I":"Intros II"
"In Library class, we have been reinforcing essential knowledge and skills from English and Thematic studies while also exploring the FDIS’s interdisciplinary curriculum.":"* seems to be enjoying engaging with the course content and working cooperatively with his peers."
"Students have been exploring interdisciplinary aspects of the FDIS curriculum while also practicing core knowledge and skills.":"I have enjoyed seeing * become engaged with my lessons and gradually become better at collaborating with his peers."
"We have been having a blast using our brains to piece together interdisciplinary concepts from English and Thematic Studies in a series of granular, serialized lessons.":"* has adapted well to the weekly routines of Library class and is growing intellectually as well as socially."

testDataM
"Allen","Miles","Weggis ","Albert "
1,2,3,1
1,2,2,2
3,1,2,2
1,2,2,2
3,3,3,3
1,2,4,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'intro.csv' file is not comma-separated, which is the default assumption of `read_csv`: `intro = read_csv('/home/patrick/Desktop/DataTest/intro.csv')`.

Instead, items in `intro.csv` are separated by `:`. Your code, as is, will have `intro.columns = [Index(['intros I:"Intros II"'], dtype='object')`, so both columns are read as one item.

To fix this, you can specify a delimiter for `read_csv`:

```
intro = read_csv('/home/patrick/Desktop/DataTest/intro.csv', sep=':')
```